# Relationship between PBR texture and mesh normals

Tags: mesh, pbr

I'm using the cloth filter to create a padded wall shape and I've fixed it so that I have mirrored it and formed an array using a square mesh. However, the PBR texture applied has some anomalies at the edges and joins which I assume are related to the mesh

[image]

Below is what the mesh looks like. The different resolutions are because I've tried to fiddle it better... its only worked a little bit to improve it

[image]

What I am unsure of is how the PBR texture get applied to the mesh and how to prevent stretches in the PBR.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hello :). Aren't the artifacts caused by the Mirror modifier? Too large 'merge distance' would be my guess :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought that might be the case but alas no... I updated the image above to reflect this